# Timing email composing in Gmail

Tags: windows, productivity, gmail

I am looking for a Windows program or Google Chrome extension that can time me when I write emails in the Gmail web interface. I.e. it should log the time I spent for each email I wrote.

Comment: I haven't found any solution so far.

Comment: So I am still interested if someone has any idea.